# Can I use `with` outside of functions?

Tags: idris

I'd like to use views and `with` in my function signature without defining an extra type-level function. Is this possible? Say I have

```
import Data.List.Views

data Foo : List Nat -> Type where
```

**What I've tried**

In a `case`

```
bar : Foo xs -> case xs with (snocList xs)
                     [] | Empty => ?rhs
                     ys + [y] | Snoc y ys rec => ?rhs'
```

but that's a syntax error. Not sure how I'd do this in a `let` block.